# Changing Diagnostic logs restarts Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When changing settings in the Diagnostic Logs blade for a Web App (example screenshot below), it will restart the Web App in question.

[image]

**Is there any way to update these settings without experiencing downtime?**

One method could be to perform this on a staging slot and then swapping it into production once it has warmed up, but is there no easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When changing settings in the Diagnostic Logs blade for a Web App (example screenshot below), it will restart the Web App

As far as I know, if we turn on Application Logging and Web Server Logging, and store logs in an Azure storage blob container, the `DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL` with configured Blob container URL will be automatically added to **App settings** and written to **Environment variables**. Then Azure Websites will detect the changes and automatically restart.

If you’d like to avoid that restarting website impact user experience, as you said, using staging slot could be a good choice.  Besides, for high availability, please try to run web site with multiple instances.

Comment: The fact that this is added as an environment variable provides a ton of context for me moving forward. It also solves another issue which I logged with Microsoft (that of my Diagnostic Settings storage settings resetting after each release).